# How powerful are the HYDRA Parasits?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

It's not stated in *Captain America: The First Avenger*, but I'm wondering
if there are any hints or sources as to what would happen if they actually detonated.

**How powerful are they?**

Answer (score 3):

The HYDRA Parasit (or rather, the bomb that they're carrying) is a powerful weapon capable of "decimating" major cities.

> **JOHANN SCHMIDT:** *I now wield enough destructive
> force to decimate every hostile
> capital on earth. Simultaneously.
> Quite simply, gentlemen...I have
> harnessed the power of the gods.*

Assuming we take him at his literal word (e.g. decimate meaning *"to kill 1 in every 10"*) and extrapolating this to the real world, it would appear that **each bomb is around 15-20Kt, similar to the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs.** I've used Vegas as my target because it's well-contained and gridded. A '*little boy*' (Hiroshima) bomb would [effectively decimate the city](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/?&kt=15&lat=36.2517808&lng=-115.2677307&hob_opt=2&hob_psi=5&hob_ft=1968&psi=20,5,1&zm=10).

[image]

If we assume that we presume him to just mean decimate as in *"cause lots of damage"*, then the sky is the limit, but I'd presume less than 1Mt because that would [obliterate rather than decimate](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/?&kt=1000&lat=36.1430065&lng=-115.1869813&hob_psi=5&hob_ft=10245&ff=50&psi=20,5,1&zm=9).

Comment: Only 6000 estimated casualties though, that's 1/100, not 1/10.

Comment: @OrangeDog - If you [drop it on the Osaka Bistro](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/?&kt=15&lat=36.144224&lng=-115.1967316&hob_opt=2&hob_psi=5&hob_ft=1968&casualties=1&psi=20,5,1&zm=13), you'll precisely decimate the city